# How to install a deprecated ports on FreeBSD

Tags: php, freebsd, ports

I'm looking for a way to install php 5.2.8 using ports on freebsd 7.0.
I just don't know how to choose php 5.2.8, make under /usr/ports/lang/php5 begins by fetching php-5.2.10.tar.bz2.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, port is version record and some patches corresponded to the version.
The easiest way to make an old version is to modify distinfo file: put 5.2.8 records in it, and try to build it. The bad things that may happen is that the port won't compile. That means you'll need patches for that version too. Now, cvs way of grabbing the whole port is almost impossible nowadays. That was the way to grab whatever you needed as what existed on a specified date with a single command. But if you don't mind to pick the required files by hand, grab them from http://cvsweb.freebsd.org/ports/lang/php5 You'd need to grab all the files in it as of 5 Mar 2009. The next day (6th) the port was updated to .9 version. So walk through the files history and download the right revisions. Back up the existent /usr/ports/lang/php5 directory, put the downloaded files there. You're ready to try building the thing.

Comment: Thank you, I juste found a port doing just that: ports-mgmt/portdowngrade but now I'm stuck with a dependency error 
===>   libmcrypt-2.5.8 depends on package: libtool>=2.2 - not found
===>   Found libtool-1.5.26, but you need to upgrade to libtool>=2.2.
*** Error code 1

I think I'll just update this server and forget my idea about using an old php version, it will be better overall anyway.

have a nice day !

Comment: Wow, i didn't know about portdowngrade. As i can see, it does the cvs trick i talked about, but, again, i cannot find alive cvs server. Maybe it's just me. Anyway, i'd try installing libmcrypt as it is in your original ports tree, then try portdowngrade the php port. Even better, install the 5.2.10 port, deinstall and downgrade.  This way the dependencies will probably be met.

Comment: I'll try this way, I haven't already did the downgrade